# Change background color effect in a item viewholder

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I have a viewholder to show a list of items. So, when I click in an item I want to change the background color of this item. And when I unclick this element I want to go back to that default background color(white).

I tried the following code but it has two problems:

1- When I unclick an item it keeps the same color(grey).

2- When I click in an item and I go two another activity, when I go back that Item keeps the same color(grey) and I don't want that. It should be in white(default color).

```
public class ArtistListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArtistListAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    // Vars
    private List<Artist> artists;
    private SearchArtistListener artistListenerAdapter;

    /************** Members **************/
    public ArtistListAdapter(List<Artist> artists, SearchArtistListener adapterListener) {
        this.artists = artists;
        this.artistListenerAdapter = adapterListener;
    }

    /************** Callbacks **************/
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista_busca, viewGroup, false);
        return (new ItemViewHolder(view, artistListenerAdapter));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int i) {
        itemViewHolder.fillFields(artists.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return artists.size();
    }

    /************** Interfaces/Classes **************/
    public final static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnTouchListener {

        // Vars
        private SearchArtistListener viewHolderListener;

        // Views
        private ImageView    imgImageView;
        private LinearLayout lnLinearLayout;
        private TextView     subtitleTextView, titleTextView;

        /************** Members **************/
        public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, SearchArtistListener viewHolderListener) {
            super(itemView);

            this.viewHolderListener = viewHolderListener;

            imgImageView   = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_lista_busca_iv_imagem);
            subtitleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_lista_busca_tv_subtitulo);
            titleTextView    = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_lista_busca_tv_titulo);
            lnLinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_lista_busca_ll);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            lnLinearLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        private void fillFields(Artist artist) {
            lnLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load(artist.getPictureSmall()).into(imgImageView);
            titleTextView.setText(artist.getName());
            subtitleTextView.setText("Artist");
        }

        /************** Callbacks **************/
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(viewHolderListener != null){
                viewHolderListener.onArtistaItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if((event.getAction()) == (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN))
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            else if((event.getAction()) == (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP))
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**************** Classes - Interfaces ****************/
    public interface SearchArtistListener {
        void onArtistaItemClick(int position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following codes to conquer both of your problems. I have used dummy codes to explain the approach.

Here is the activity bearing your recyclerview. Just make an interface and implement its method on resume, and use that interface in your viewholder,
so when the activity resumes it will implement the function and will turn the color back to default.

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

    private OnActivityRefresh onActivityRefresh;

    public void setOnActivityRefresh(OnActivityRefresh onActivityRefresh) {
        this.onActivityRefresh = onActivityRefresh;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(onActivityRefresh != null){
            onActivityRefresh.onRefresh();
        }

    }

    private void refreshRecyclerview() {

    }

    public interface OnActivityRefresh{
        void onRefresh();
    }

}
```

Now here is the typical view holder. Here I have used the same activity as an argument in the constructor and have set the interface, which finally runs the refresh function on activity resume

Moreover I have made a toggle effect just by using simple click listener on mother layout. Here mother layout is the child's mother layout:

```
public class TestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    private LinearLayout mother_layout;
    private boolean isViewSelected = false;

    public TestViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        initViews(itemView);
    }

    private void initViews(View v){
        mother_layout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.mother_layout);
    }

    public void init(Activity activity){
        ((TestActivity)activity).setOnActivityRefresh(new TestActivity.OnActivityRefresh() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                isViewSelected = false;
                setDefaultColor();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == mother_layout){
            if(isViewSelected){
                isViewSelected = false;
                setDefaultColor();
            }else{
                isViewSelected = true;
                setActiveColor();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setActiveColor() {

    }

    private void setDefaultColor() {

    }

}
```